# How to replace every occurence of a value with another one in a binary tree with Prolog

Tags: replace, tree, prolog

I have a problem with my code and I can not figure out why it does not work for me. It stops at the first occurens and just replaces one occurens. The task is to replace every occurence of a value with another one in a binary tree like the example below.

Thats a example tree:

```
testTreeReplace(t2, tree(a,tree(1,tree(a,tree(6,-,-),tree(9,-,-)),-),tree(8,-,tree(a,tree(20,-,-),tree(3,-,-))))).
```

and thats the code I use:

```
replace(X,Y,TreeIn,TreeOut) :-
    testTreeReplace(TreeIn,T),
    replaceH(X,Y,T,TreeOut).

replaceH(X,Y,tree(X,L,R),tree(Y,L,R)).

replaceH(X,Y,tree(A,L,R),tree(A,L,New)) :-
    replaceH(X,Y,R,New).

replaceH(X,Y,tree(A,L,R),tree(A,New,R)) :-
    replaceH(X,Y,L,New).
```

and the ouput is:

```
?- replace(a,b,t2,Res).
Res = tree(b, tree(1, tree(a, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(a, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))) ;
Res = tree(a, tree(1, tree(a, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(b, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))) ;
Res = tree(a, tree(1, tree(b, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(a, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))) ;
false.
```

but it should be

```
Res = tree(b, tree(1, tree(b, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(b, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))).
```

(all the a's should be b's)

Further more I dont want to use additional librarys. Thank you in advance

Comment: In your predicate you branch: in one branch you replace the left subtree, in another the right subtree (and at the top, you only replace the element itself).

Comment: Do you have any idea to change my code, so the whole thing works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not branch in the recursion, since that means that in one of the answers, you will only replace the element (if it matches), in *another* answer you will recurse on the left subtree, and in another one in the right subtree.

We can thus first make a predicate that checks if `Z` is equal to `X` and in case it

```
replaceValue(X, Y, Z, R) :-
    (  X == Z
    -> R = Y
    ;  R = Z
    ).
```

Then we can thus make a predicate that will for a tree try to replace the value of the tree, and in the same branch also replaces `X`s by `Y`s in the left and right subtree:

```
replaceTree(X,Y,tree(Z, L, R),tree(Z2, L2, R2)) :-
    replaceValue(X, Y, Z, Z2),
    replaceTree(X, Y, L, L2),
    replaceTree(X, Y, R, R2).
replaceTree(_, _, -, -).
```

This thus gives us:

```
?- replaceTree(a, b, tree(a, tree(1, tree(a, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(a, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))), T).
T = tree(b, tree(1, tree(b, tree(6, -, -), tree(9, -, -)), -), tree(8, -, tree(b, tree(20, -, -), tree(3, -, -)))) ;
false.
```

Comment: I think it's hard to pick an appropriate equality here - on one hand, I would imagine that often we;'d really like to search for a particular occurrence (like you implemented) but it would exclude interesting applications like moving all items from the kitchen to the closet (i.e. replace `loc(X, kitchen)` by `loc(X, closet)`).